# Connect Excel to AWS Postgresql db

Tags: excel, postgresql, odbc

I am trying to get data from an AWS postgresql db into Excel and I am really struggling. When I select get data from postgresql it complains about missing additional components which I downloaded and installed but still the same issue.
I tried to use and ODBC connector but I have no idea how to use it and with many tries I still didn't get it right.
I have zero idea what to do. I currently connect to this db using Dbeaver, but thats not ideal.
I am able to connect to teradata using excel.

I dont even know what other info i need to provide here

Answer (score 0):

You may find downloading the relevant data to a tab-separated value (TSV) or a comma-separated value (CSV) file first and then importing that into Excel might be easier to deal with than trying to hook into ODBC.

Almost every database client supports export to CSV and most also support TSV. Excel is really good at [importing these kinds of files](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/all/how-do-1-open-a-tsv-file-into-excel/3396cf11-8b91-4b7a-a327-3d60d9cc640e).

Comment: Key point is to *import* the file. Same goes for a CSV.